# preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php

```
A qué se debe este error? preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash, este es mi código.

$directory = URL::to('/images/events/96331140/');
foreach (preg_match($directory . '*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE) as $archivo) {
echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de tipo imagen.<br>\n";
}
```

Hice lo siguiente:

```
foreach (preg_match('/'. $directory .'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE) as $archivo) {
                            echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de tipo imagen.<br>\n";
                        }
```

y también

```
foreach (preg_match( $directory .'/'.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE) as $archivo) {
                            echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de tipo imagen.<br>\n";
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

El delimitador se debe usar al principio y al fin de la expresión, en tu codigo:

```
foreach (preg_match('/'. $directory .'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE) as $archivo) {
                            echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de tipo imagen.<br>\n";
                        }
```

utilizas "/" comenzando, pero no existe el cierre de la expresión con otro "/".

Comment: Gracias, me muestra el siguiente error:  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/'  para intentar solucionarlo cambié comillas simples por dobles, agragué otro '/' después de la variable, y sigue igual

Comment: @joe ¿ puedes poner como quedo la linea de codigo?

Comment: foreach (preg_match('/'. $directory .'.'/'.*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE) as $archivo) {
                            echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de tipo imagen.<br>\n";
                        }

Comment: Inicialmente como lo publicaste, después leyendo en el manual ví que debe llevar un / de cierre

Comment: @Joe lo que puse, fue una copia de tu codigo para apoyarme y decir que "no existe cierre de la expresión", te funciono ahora?

Comment: No, áun así no funciona